# Loopback doesn't filter if value contain .(dot)

Tags: filter, where-clause, loopback

I am using loopback3, I am trying to get the data through where filter but it is not able to find if the value containing . (dot )

here is my filter clause
`{"where": {"name": "S.k. Gupta Attamimi"}}`  I get empty response body. although record has this value

Thanks

Comment: I have deleted the previous one and created new one , and then i applied same filter it's working now. dont know what was the problem earlier.